# Syncing strategy as long as the app is running

Tags: android

I have an application which contains around 10 and more activities.

I am trying to accomplish a sync with a back end server. (I send some data, and get some data back, which I store in Databases, etc)

I want to keep the sync running as long as my app is visible. My problem is there's no real concept of "my app is now running" on Android. Also, the user can have so many exit points that it will be difficult to know in which onPause/onStop I should place my code. (correct me and explain please if I am wrong here).

Please note that I will not be changing an GUI related stuff from this sync mechanism.

I was suggested couple of solutions which can be summerized as below.

1. Do a service and bind it to each activity. As long as the service has an owner, it runs, as long as it does not, it is stopped.
2. Use a reference counter for the sync. Get a singleton class that runs the sync and on each onStart and onStop, add or subtract my counter, and stop the sync when the counter is 0.
3. Subclass the application context (or make static variables) to see the state of each activity, and inside each onResume and onPause do a check and start/pause/stop the sync accordingly.

Which approach is recommended and if there are another ideas, kindly share.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html). There is a [Google IO Session on how to sync your app with sync adapter from 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=xHXn3Kg2IQE#t=2636). (the link contains the time where it starts to get interesting for you if this does not work, its starts at min 44)

If you don't want to use the SycAdapter and your goal is to sync ONLY if the app is visible you could do the following:

Create a `Service`. Start/Restart it on every `onResume()` of your Activity (= app gets in forground), stop it on every `onStop()` or `onPause()` (=app gets in background). If the service is running it syncs your data. Once no activity is visible there is no sync. You could use the mentioned ref counter to keep the service running during the whole foreground phase, this is dependet on how your sync is implemented (short vs. long sync)

Comment: 10x a lot. However, it might be better in my case to look for a service/thread sort of mechanism rather than implement the SyncAdapter.